# error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'int'

Tags: c++, qt, c++17, converters, initializer-list

So I'm trying to initialize QCoreApplication without any arguments (within my test), and I just could get rid of `error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'int'`

I'm trying to provide the char** by this:

```
char* args[] = {(char*)"foo"};
int i = 1;
QCoreApplication app(i, args);
```

the constructor of [QCoreApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html) is declared as followed: `QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication(int &argc, char **argv)`

I know I need to convert the parameter explicitly, but I just couldn't figure it out how, so any hint how I can satisfy the compiler (MSVC22 with C++ 17 standard)?

EDIT:
minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <QObject>

int main(){
    char* args[] = {(char*)"foo"};
    int i = 1;
    QCoreApplication app(i, args);
    app.exec();
}
```

error output:

```
test.cpp(6,22): error C2079: 'app' uses undefined class 'QCoreApplication'
test.cpp(6,33): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'int' 
test.cpp(6,25): message : The initializer contains too many elements
```

Comment: The constructor you are showing wants a non-`const` lvalue reference to `int`. You can't pass it a literal `1`. It should be a reference to a variable. Also, casting away `const` from the string literal is a disaster waiting to happen. If you are not absolutely sure `QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication` will not try to modify the string, then do not do that. Any such modification will result in undefined behavior. Avoid C-style casts in general.

Comment: But the error message you are showing does not match the code you are showing. There is no attempt to  convert from an "initializer list" to a `int`. Please show a proper [mre] that can be used to reproduce the exact error message.

Comment: `char* args[]` -> `const char* args[]` and remove the cast.

Comment: @user17732522: minimal example provided. You need to take care of the Qt installation by yourself btw. According to your first comment: agree with your notice, I'm just trying to keep the equation as simple as possible, as I've tried all kind of conversions I know.

Comment: @JasonLiam: ```const char* args[] = {"foo"};``` still doesn't help, with exact the same error message.

Comment: @dboy [You cannot pass a literal to an argument taking a non-const reference](https://godbolt.org/z/4sPWPcG9T)

Comment: you are missing the header `#include <QCoreApplication>` as the class `QCoreApplication` is defined in that header